# Incrementation in python (a*=b)

Tags: python, python-3.x, increment

> Q.) WRITE THE OUTPUT OF THE FOLLOWING:
>
> ```
> a=12
> b=7.4
> c=1
> a-=b
> print(a,b)            # I understood this much
> a*=2+c
> print(a)
> ```

My answer is 10.2 whereas the answer should be 13.799999999999999

Comment: Do you have a question?  What part don't you understand?  Are you supposed to do this in your head or use an interpreter?

Comment: I just ran through your code and got 13.79 repeating, not sure what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The `*=` augmented assignment will evaluate all of the right hand side and then multiply the left hand side by the result. You are confusing operator priorities here and think that the addition happens after the multiplication but that isn't the case.

So before the augmented assignment `a` is `4.6` and `c` is `1`, then `a *= 2+c` is the same as `a *= 3` which is `a = a * 3` or about `13.8` (`repr` is 13.79999... but if you use `print` it will round to a sensible number).